# The git repository at '/Users/theartist' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have this issue where it says that.

I tried following the other questions that were asked here such as removing and clearing everything.
Pushing and pulling and it came out as fatal.

I also took a look and these are the files. I don't recognize them anywhere.

All I did was remove folders and files I no longer needed and then I reinstalled them from their repositories to see if that was it, but it still causes this issue when I create new files locally like a file or folder instead through GitHub.

PLEASE HELP!
I run on a 2020 MacBook Pro with the intel chip.

To recap here's what I have done

1. Discard Changes on VSCODE. Didn't work as it gave me a '`fatal: you are on a branch yet to be born`'
2. I tried pushing and committing and nothing (obviously but it was worth a try)
3. ran the commands `git reset`. Didn't work.

[image: files that need to be committed]

Comment: is your workspace directory `~/.vscode`, that is WRONG

Comment: How can I fix this? It comes up like that automatically

Comment: You must have sometime used the command `Open Folder` and choose the worst folder possible. Open a folder where your project files really are and not a subdir of `~/.vscode`

Comment: Hmm. So the new file I made was put in a folder that is located on the desktop. It was fine earlier but now this occurred. Can you clarify more what you mean and what I should do next? Sorry I am new here! It like it just automatically puts it in that directory. How can I change that?

Comment: they have written very nice doc pages for VSC, read the getting started chapter

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to the workspace folder opened by VSCode.

What I prefer to do is:

- create a folder for a specific project in `~/myNewproject`
- go to that folder: `cd ~/myNewProject`
- open vscode from there: `vscode .`
- save that as a workspace in `~/myNewproject/.vscode/myNewProject.workspace`
- Start adding files there

That way, the number of files monitored by VSCode remains contained to that specific project.

Consider combining this approach with the [`files.exclude` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_explorer)

> By default, VS Code excludes some folders from the Explorer (for example. `.git/`).
> Use the files.exclude [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to configure rules for hiding files and folders from the Explorer.
>
> Tip: This is really useful to hide derived resources files, like `\*.meta` in Unity, or `\*.js` in a TypeScript project.
>
> - For Unity to exclude the `\*.cs.meta` files, the pattern to choose would be: `"**/*.cs.meta": true`.
> - For TypeScript, you can exclude generated JavaScript for TypeScript files with: `"**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `.gitignore` file, and add the `.vscode` directory to exclude it.

sample `.gitignore` file

```
.vscode/
```